# Mysql one middle table for multiple similar tables

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have a table called *category*. There are some tables relates to category table. For example, user has category, post has category etc. Each one must have their own middle table to relates to the category table. (ex: a post have a lot of categories)

Now there are *two different approaches*:

**First**: each table (like user, post ...) has own middle table related to `category` table.

**Second**: there is one middle table for all tables, separated by a column called `type` (type can have these values: *user* , *post* , etc). (here there is no foreign key, because foreign key is virtual)

Which one is better? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have distinct entity sets (like `User` and `Post`) that aren't subtypes of a higher type, I recommend the first approach - make separate relationship tables. The reason for this is to stick closely to the fundamental concept of a logical relation, which requires that each component/role have a single domain.

This will significantly simplify queries and consistency in the long run. If you mix different sets of ID values into the same column, it'll prevent you from using unique constraints and foreign key constraints to ensure integrity, and your queries will need conditional logical to handle the different cases.

When you have subsets of a higher type - like `Customer` and `Employee`, which are both subsets of `Person`, the ideal is to create a supertype table and then create the relationship on the supertype. This is much easier to do during the design phase than after your database is populated with data.